# How can I use forEach to set dynamic variables in JavaScript and jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a jQuery plugin.  There is an object of options that I want to loop through to set regular variables with. It would basically set a variable that would be the index of the object item.  I want to determine if any options are left blank and if they are, set the regular variable to the default value.  I would usually use the following to set options to a default if they are blank:

```
 var defaults = {
     someVar1 : "somevar1",
      omeVar2:  "somevar2"
 };

var someVar1;
var someVar2;

function init(options, defaults){
   if(typeof options.someVar1 === 'undefined'){
      someVar1 = defaults.someVar1;
   } else {
      someVar1 = options.someVar1;
  }
   return something();
}
function something(){
   console.log(item);
});
```

This can be a big pain in the butt if I have a lot of options to set.  How could I modify my code below to dynamically define global variables?

```
function init(element, options){
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $.each(options, function(index, value){
             if(typeof options.index === 'undefined'){

              }
         });
     });
 }
```

Comment: just use `$.extend` to merge user defined options with your defaults. You normally wouldn't have `$(document).ready` within your plugin code

Comment: Yeah I actually do use $.extend I just didn't think it was relevant enough to include it here.

Comment: why do you need all these individual variables then? After you merge user opts with defaults just use `if` on final object properties

Comment: Doing it that way will make the code much cleaner rather than having to use an if for every action I preform.

Comment: whatever works for you, doesn't make much sense without seeing more of the plugin code. Normally you would be testing after the `$.extend`

Comment: here's a jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/dgngczuu/

Comment: this is what I mean `var settings = $.extend(defaults,options);` then forget about `options` and just use `settings` in rest of your code

Answer (score 1):

Lets say you have an object :

```
var my_object = {
    item1 : 1,
    item2 : 2,
    item3 : 3,
}

var i;
for(i in my_object){
    console.log(i); 
    console.log(my_object[i]);
}
/*
    This will print in the console:
    item1
    1
    item2
    2
    item3
    3
*/
```

for each will not find an undefined, because undefined does not exist, unless your object is like this:

```
var my_object = {
    item1 : 1,
    item2 : 2,
    item3 : 3,
    item4 : undefined
}
```

Also :

```
$.each(options, function(index, value){
  // if(typeof options.index === 'undefined'){ <-- this is wrong
     if(typeof options[index]=== 'undefined'){ <-- this is correct
        // Also you have the value, why not "value === undefined" ?
     }
});
```

Comment: I guess I could use the .each on my defaults object instead of options.  PS:  I didn't think to include that object when I posted my example :/

Comment: And so how would I use the index to define a variable?

Comment: One more thing... why is options.index wrong?  Wouldn't you use that since you're working with an object?

Comment: `index` is a variable. When you say `object.index` it's like saying `object['index']`, the index here is not a variable its the key.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might want to setup a predefined variable array then based on your index of the option read its default value

```
var optionDefaults = ["val1", "val2", "val3"];
function init(element, options){
    $(document).ready(function(){
         $.each(options, function(index, value){
             if(typeof options.index === 'undefined'){
                  var optiondefValue = optionDefaults[index];
                  //do whatever you want here.
              }
         });
     });
 }
```